# Can't deploy the mariadb on k8s cluster with helm

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I'm in the process of learning helm and trying to deploy the mariadb on my k8s cluster running on the DigitalOcean with 1 master and 2 worker nodes with the following command:

```
helm install my-mariadb bitnami/mariadb --version 12.2.2
```

This in turn created multiple resources on the cluster including the PersistenVolumeClaim, which failed to spin up and gets stuck in the Pending state with the following error: `no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set`. This error in turn keeps all the pods being in the Pending state as well.

Why does this resource even gets created? After looking into the templates of this helm chart [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mariadb) I can't even find the definition of it there.

If that's actually fine that I can't see it, then why there's no StorageClass or PersistentVolume in deployed resources? Doesn't seem right to create them manually.

Comment: The StorageClass is part of cluster configuration; a process called a _provisioner_ should create PersistentVolumes when PersistentVolumeClaims are created.  You should not normally need to create either and it would be inappropriate for a public chart to include them.

Comment: This error usually comes in kubernetes set with kubeadm. Refer to [Helm issues](https://linuxthegreat.wordpress.com/), which may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

So, turns out that this problem arise only on the k8s cluster that's set up with kubeadm. I've fixed this issue by creating my own PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim as described in the link provided in the comments, but then faced another problems: the mariadb pod's container crashes as it can't create `/bitnami/mariadb/data` folder due to permission error.

I was able to make this work on the local single-node k8s cluster without any additional steps and decided to abandon to try to resolve this issue on initial cluster, as I do this only for studying.